# How to download from a shared drive in google drive with python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

The problem I have is that it is not able to find files inside the folder I specify and I don't know if it is because something is missing or how to modify it so that it downloads different folders in different directories on my computer.
Folder 1 to destination 1, folder 2 to destination 2 and so on.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import shutil
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# Ruta al archivo de credenciales JSON descargado desde la Consola de Desarrolladores de Google
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\credentials.json'

# Ruta a la base de datos local
DATABASE_FILE = 'sync_database.db'

# Ruta a la carpeta temporal donde se descargarán los archivos
CARPETA_TEMPORAL = 'C:\\Users\\adria\\Downloads\\CARPETATEMPORAL'

# Diccionario que relaciona las IDs de las carpetas en Google Drive con las rutas de destino en tu PC
CARPETAS_SINCRONIZADAS = {
    '1AW6....75rms3': '\\\\192.168.0.000\\Shared\\Anime\\animename',
    }
    # Agrega más entradas para sincronizar más carpetas de origen y destino

# Ruta de carpeta compartida de Google Drive
ID_CARPETA_COMPARTIDA = '1AW6....075rms3'

def crear_tabla():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archivos (
            id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            nombre TEXT,
            ultima_modificacion TEXT
        )
    ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def agregar_archivo_descargado(carpeta_id, nombre_archivo, ultima_modificacion):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO archivos (id, nombre, ultima_modificacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                   (carpeta_id, nombre_archivo, ultima_modificacion))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def autenticar():
    creds = None

    # Verificar si ya existe un archivo de token para reutilizar las credenciales previas
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])

    # Si no hay credenciales válidas, solicitar autorización
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Guardar las credenciales para su reutilización
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def obtener_subcarpetas_de_carpeta_compartida(servicio_drive, carpeta_id):
    resultados = servicio_drive.files().list(q=f"'{carpeta_id}' in parents",
                                             fields="files(id, name, parents, modifiedTime)").execute()
    subcarpetas = resultados.get('files', [])
    return subcarpetas

def descargar_archivos_desde_drive():
    # Autenticar con la API de Google Drive
    servicio_drive = autenticar()

    # Crear la tabla en la base de datos si no existe
    crear_tabla()

    # Obtener la lista de subcarpetas dentro de la carpeta compartida en Google Drive
    subcarpetas_carpeta_compartida = obtener_subcarpetas_de_carpeta_compartida(servicio_drive, ID_CARPETA_COMPARTIDA)

    for carpeta_id, ruta_destino in CARPETAS_SINCRONIZADAS.items():
        print(f"Procesando carpeta: {carpeta_id} (Carpeta destino: {ruta_destino})")

        # Obtener la lista de archivos en la carpeta en Google Drive
        resultados = servicio_drive.files().list(q=f"'{carpeta_id}' in parents",
                                                 fields="files(id, name, parents, modifiedTime)").execute()
        archivos_carpeta = resultados.get('files', [])

        if not archivos_carpeta:
            print(f"No se encontraron archivos en la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id} en Google Drive.")
        else:
            print(f"Descargando archivos de la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id}")

            for archivo in archivos_carpeta:
                archivo_id = archivo['id']
                archivo_nombre = archivo['name']
                archivo_ultima_modificacion = archivo['modifiedTime']

                # Descargar el archivo a la carpeta destino en tu PC
                try:
                    request = servicio_drive.files().get_media(fileId=archivo_id)
                    ruta_archivo_completa = os.path.join(ruta_destino, archivo_nombre)
                    with open(ruta_archivo_completa, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(request.execute())

                    # Actualizar la información en la base de datos
                    agregar_archivo_descargado(archivo_id, archivo_nombre, archivo_ultima_modificacion)
                    print(f"Archivo descargado: {archivo_nombre}")

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error al descargar el archivo {archivo_nombre}: {e}")

            print(f"Proceso de descarga de la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id} completado.")

    print("Proceso de descarga y sincronización completado.")
    messagebox.showinfo("Descarga completada", "El proceso de descarga y sincronización de archivos desde Google Drive ha sido completado.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    descargar_archivos_desde_drive()
```

I don't have much idea, I help myself with chatgpt but I have entered a loop of errors and answers that make me unable to move forward. What I'm looking for is to keep some anime series from a shared folder synchronized with my pc folder and that even if they change the name according to the code there is a database that does not download the same file after downloading, so it is not downloaded in duplicate by changing the name.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

----------------------- Edit --------------

The code that I leave here below is the one that already works correctly according to my scheme of folders in google drive, the functions of this code are to download from a folder in google drive that I have read access, there are a series of folders with series and each series has different qualities, so what it does is to download the series that I want in the quality that I choose indicating the ID of the google folder and indicating the destination on my pc, also creates a database that does not re-download the file once it has been downloaded to avoid duplicates by changing the names and indicates percentage of downloaded process as a final message at the end.
Thank you very much

```
    import os
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import shutil
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from tqdm import tqdm  # Importa el módulo tqdm

# Ruta al archivo de credenciales JSON descargado desde la Consola de Desarrolladores de Google
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\credentials.json'

# Ruta a la base de datos local
DATABASE_FILE = 'sync_database.db'

# Ruta a la carpeta temporal donde se descargarán los archivos
CARPETA_TEMPORAL = 'C:\\Users\\namepc\\Downloads\\CARPETATEMPORAL'

# Diccionario que relaciona los IDs de las carpetas en Google Drive con las rutas de destino en tu PC
CARPETAS_SINCRONIZADAS = {
    '1AW6....W075rms3': '\\\\192.168.0.000\\Shared\\Anime\\Anime1',
    '1_NRUE2o.....2HFkWlnO': '\\\\192.168.0.000\\Shared\\Anime\\Anime2',
    '1zXBp....YxToCDb4ik': '\\\\192.168.2.164\\Shared\\Anime\\Anime3',
    
}
# Agrega más entradas para sincronizar más carpetas de origen y destino

def crear_tabla():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archivos (
            id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            nombre TEXT,
            ultima_modificacion TEXT
        )
    ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def agregar_archivo_descargado(carpeta_id, nombre_archivo, ultima_modificacion):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO archivos (id, nombre, ultima_modificacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                   (carpeta_id, nombre_archivo, ultima_modificacion))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def archivo_ya_descargado(archivo_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM archivos WHERE id = ?', (archivo_id,))
    resultado = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return resultado is not None


def autenticar():
    creds = None

    # Verificar si ya existe un archivo de token para reutilizar las credenciales previas
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])

    # Si no hay credenciales válidas, solicitar autorización
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Guardar las credenciales para su reutilización
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def obtener_subcarpetas_de_carpeta_compartida(servicio_drive, carpeta_id):
    resultados = servicio_drive.files().list(
        corpora="drive",
        driveId="0AC.....9PVA",  # Reemplaza con el ID real de tu drive compartido
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        q=f"'{carpeta_id}' in parents",
        fields="files(id, name, parents, modifiedTime)"
    ).execute()
    subcarpetas = resultados.get('files', [])
    return subcarpetas

def obtener_archivos_de_subcarpeta(servicio_drive, subcarpeta_id):
    resultados = servicio_drive.files().list(
        q=f"'{subcarpeta_id}' in parents",
        fields="files(id, name, modifiedTime)"
    ).execute()
    archivos_subcarpeta = resultados.get('files', [])
    return archivos_subcarpeta

def obtener_archivos_de_carpeta(servicio_drive, carpeta_id):
    resultados = servicio_drive.files().list(
        corpora="drive",
        driveId="0ACl.....9PVA",
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        q=f"'{carpeta_id}' in parents",
        fields="files(id, name, parents, modifiedTime, mimeType)"
    ).execute()
    archivos = resultados.get('files', [])
    return archivos

def descargar_archivos_desde_drive():
    # Autenticar con la API de Google Drive
    servicio_drive = autenticar()

    # Crear la tabla en la base de datos si no existe
    crear_tabla()

    for carpeta_id, ruta_destino in CARPETAS_SINCRONIZADAS.items():
        print(f"Procesando carpeta: {carpeta_id} (Carpeta destino: {ruta_destino})")

        # Obtener la lista de archivos en la carpeta en Google Drive
        archivos_carpeta = obtener_archivos_de_carpeta(servicio_drive, carpeta_id)

        # Verificar si hay archivos en la carpeta
        if not archivos_carpeta:
            print(f"No se encontraron archivos en la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id}")
            continue

        for archivo in tqdm(archivos_carpeta, desc=f"Descargando archivos de la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id}"):
            archivo_id = archivo['id']
            archivo_nombre = archivo['name']

            # Verificar si el archivo ya ha sido descargado previamente (consultando la base de datos)
            if archivo_ya_descargado(archivo_id):
                print(f"El archivo {archivo_nombre} ya ha sido descargado previamente. Saltando la descarga.")
                continue

            # Descargar el archivo a la carpeta destino en tu PC
            try:
                request = servicio_drive.files().get_media(fileId=archivo_id)
                ruta_archivo_completa = os.path.join(ruta_destino, archivo_nombre)
                with open(ruta_archivo_completa, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(request.execute())

                # Actualizar la información en la base de datos
                agregar_archivo_descargado(archivo_id, archivo_nombre, archivo['modifiedTime'])
                print(f"Archivo descargado: {archivo_nombre}")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error al descargar el archivo {archivo_nombre}: {e}")

        print(f"Proceso de descarga de archivos completado para la carpeta con ID {carpeta_id}")

    print("Proceso de descarga y sincronización completado.")
    messagebox.showinfo("Descarga completada", "El proceso de descarga y sincronización de archivos desde Google Drive ha sido completado.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    descargar_archivos_desde_drive()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.